# Bizzare problem with ModelForm and Unit Tests: TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

Tags: python, django, forms

I have *no* clue what could be going on here:

**models.py**

```
class Sound(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female')
    )
    phrase1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phrase2 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    num_words = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="number of words")
    num_syllables = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="number of syllables")
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    voice = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="synthetic voice")
    speaker_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sound_hash = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200, editable=False, default="", null=True, help_text="Amazon S3 key")
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
class LessonSoundForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sound
        fields = ["phrase1", "phrase2", "num_words", "num_syllables"]
```

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from forms import LessonSoundForm
class LessonSoundForm(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.sound_data = {
                "phrase1": "Poop",
                "phrase2": "Knuckle",
                "num_words": 1,
                "num_syllables": 1
        }

    def test_lesson_sound_form_validates_with_good_data(self):
        form = LessonSoundForm(data=self.sound_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

This seems super simple, and all other tests validate using `ModelForm`. I get this error, though:

```
line 20, in test_lesson_sound_form_validates_with_good_data
        form = LessonSoundForm(data=self.sound_data)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

If I run it w/o the `data` argument, I get:

```
    form = LessonSoundForm(self.sound_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 397, in __init__
    testMethod = getattr(self, methodName)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

This seems like a very basic case, and I have **no** clue what could be going wrong. I assume it's just the end of the day and I'm missing something stupid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from forms import LessonSoundForm
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class LessonSoundForm(TestCase):
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're overwriting `LessonSoundForm` when you're defining a new class for your test case because of **same name**.

Comment: ... yup. yesterday was a *long* day.

Comment: Damn, this is hard to catch if you're way into the code